# WPF MVVM Binding visibility to dynamic MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, prism

How to update Context MenuItem when Commands `CanExecute*` method change it's state.

I have a problem regarding binding `visibility` to dynamicaly created `MenuItems` (based on `ICommands` and `DataTemplates`).
`ContextMenu` is created for GridControl which binds some custom parameters.
I managed to bind those parameters via `Freezable` proxy to `ContextMenu`.
All works allmost OK, except `CanExecute*` does not change `MenuItem` visbility.
If `CanExecute*` have constant `e.CanExecute = true`, than it's OK (menuitem is active), but when `CanExecute*` have some logic and can have both states, than `MenuItem` always have `IsEnabled` set to false

Some code:
ContextCommands  is extension of ICommand

```
IEnumerable<ICommand<SomeClass>> ContextCommands
```

CustomMenuItem

```
//CustomMenuItem is just extension of MenuItem  
public class CustomMenuItem : MenuItem
```

DataTemplates

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type....
<controls:CustomMenuItem Command="{Binding Path=WrappedCommand}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
<commandparameters ... (parameters works OK, so i skip that)>
```

Grid Declaration

```
<controls:CustomGridControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyGrid"
                                   ColumnDescriptions="{Binding Source.ColumnDescriptions}" 
                                   QueryableSource="{Binding Source.Query}"
                                   Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                                    >
    <controls:CustomGridControl.Resources>
        <helpers:BindingProxyHelper x:Key="DataProxy" Data="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </controls:CustomGridControl.Resources>
    <controls:CustomGridControl.ContextMenu>
        <contextmenu:CustomContextMenu 
            DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ContextCommands}"
            BindableProperties="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource DataProxy}, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </contextmenu:CustomContextMenu>
    </controls:CustomGridControl.ContextMenu>
</controls:CustomGridControl>
```

How to invoke Visibility to dynamic MenuItem when CanExecute changes?
I tried to pass DataContext but that has no effect, UI does not changes
Debuging this binding shows that Visibility is correctly set, but without effect.

```
CAN EDIT FALSE
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=2852357) for Binding (hash=35737921)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'IsVisible'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): Attach to Controls.CustomMenuItem.Visibility (hash=36410781)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): Found data context element: CustomMenuItem (hash=36410781) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): Activate with root item CommandWithParameterPlugin`1 (hash=19041329)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357):   At level 0 - for CommandWithParameterPlugin`1.IsVisible found accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsVisible)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): Replace item at level 0 with CommandWithParameterPlugin`1 (hash=19041329), using accessor ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsVisible)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): GetValue at level 0 from CommandWithParameterPlugin`1 (hash=19041329) using ReflectPropertyDescriptor(IsVisible): 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): TransferValue - got raw value 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 82 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): TransferValue - user's converter produced 'Visible'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=2852357): TransferValue - using final value 'Visible'
CAN EDIT TRUE
CAN EDIT TRUE
```

I've looked in stackoverflow for answers, found a lot of suggestions, but still no luck with my problem.

I assume problem might be with assingning Binding ContextCommands to CustomContextMenu, since it may be outside of the visualtree. Solution probably might be some kind of proxy for that, but i have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); may be what you are looking for ?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, when debuging CanExecute i see it's Raised, but there's no effect for the UI (see my last paragraph)

Comment: Have you tired [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @mechanic yes, i use it. PS. i updated last Output info, to show when CanExexute* is called and what value it tries to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve problem with accessing menuItem visibility through command and binding command and parameters was to set data templates in MenuItem style
Since there is multiple command types in project selection is made through TypeNameConverter

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeNameConverter}}" Value="CommandType`1">
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding SomeParametersFromParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomContextMenu}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=HeaderInfo}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
```

Hope this helps some of you with similar problem